# Problems with angular promises' responses in services

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript, angular-promise

I'm working with angular 1.2.18 for the first time.  I am using it with rails 3.2 and coffeescript.  I am trying to use a promise in a service to fetch some data that I will then use to populate a template. My code looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.service('fetchService', ['$http', '$q', ($http, $q) ->
 theService = {}
  theService.myData = null

  theService.getData = (url) ->
    q = $q.defer()

    if this.myData
      q.resolve(this.myData)
      return q.promise

    self = this
    $http.get(url).then(
      (successResonse)->
        self.myData = successResponse
        q.resolve(successResponse)
      ,(errorResponse)->
        self.myData = errorResponse
        q.reject(errorResponse)
    )

    return q.promise
  return theService
])

.directive('myDirective', ["fetchService", fetchService)->
  return {
    restrict: "A"
    templateUrl: "/my_template_url"
    scope:
      url: '@shopUrl'
      offset: '@'
        controller: ($scope, fetchService)->
      fetchService.getData($scope.url).success( (data) ->
        $scope.content = data.content
      )
  }
])
```

When I try to do this, I get "undefined is not a function" and no useful stack trace.  I am not sure which part is undefined.  I have thought about doing this in a config(), but I don't know what the url in $http.get(url) is until runtime. Any help or advice on doing this the "angular way" would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchService.getData` is returning a `$q` promise, not an `$http` promise, so you can't call `.success on it.

```
fetchService.getData($scope.url).success( (data) ->
```

This needs to be changed to

```
fetchService.getData($scope.url).then( (data) ->
```